# Can anyone explain this weird behaviour of shutil.rmtree and shutil.copytree?

Tags: python, windows, shutil

I'm building a relatively simple application that asks for directories, checks if they're correct, and then removes one of them and recreates it with contents of the other one. I'm encountering this weird behaviour, I'll try to explain:

When I've got the destination folder window open, AND it's empty, there's an access denied exception, then I get kicked out of the folder and it gets removed. But then if it's not empty, it works just fine, no exceptions, the destination directory (from what it seems) gets emptied then filled with files from the source directory. Which is strange because it's supposed to straight out remove the destination folder no matter what, and then recreate it with the same name and contents from the source destination.

This doesn't make sense to me, shouldn't there be the exact same exception when I'm browsing the directory when it's not empty as when it's empty? What's the difference, it's still supposed to just delete the folder. Is there any logical explanation to that? Also, if there's an exception, why does the directory get removed anyway?

Code for this particular part is pretty straightforward (please keep in mind I'm a beginner :) )

```
def Delete(self, dest):

    try:
        shutil.rmtree(dest)
        self.Paste(self.src, dest)
    except (IOError, os.error) as e:
        print e

def Paste(self, src, dest):

    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest)
    except (IOError, os.error) as e:
        print e
```

Comment: Are you getting the access denied exception from `Delete()` or `Paste()`? It's hard to tell when there are multiple statement in a `try` block. It might be best to add the entire traceback the your question. Be sure to indent it by 4 spaces so it will be readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour on Windows.

Internally `shutil.rmtree` calls the windows API function `DeleteFile` which is documented on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This function has the following property (highlight by me):

> The DeleteFile function marks a file for deletion on close. **Therefore, the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed.** Subsequent calls to CreateFile to open the file fail with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

If any other process still has a handle open (e.g. virus scanners, windows explorer because you watch the directory or anything else that might still have a handle to that directory), it will not go away.

Usually you just catch the exception in your Paste operation and retry it a few times/for some dozend milliseconds, to handle all those weird virus scanner anomalies.

Little bonus: You can use windbg or ProcessExplorer to find out who still keeps an open handle to your file (just use Find Handle in Process explorer and search for the filename).

Comment: Alright, but that still doesn't explain why there is no issue when the directory is not empty, which confuses me most. Once again: the program is supposed to delete the directory no matter what. When I'm watching the directory in windows explorer AND it's empty, there's an exception, but if it's not empty, then there is no problem whatsoever, and I'm able to watch the files get pasted, while the folder is supposedly being deleted and recreated

Comment: Well, this is a race condition. If the directory is empty, you have the shortest possible case (just a single `DeleteFile`), if it is not empty, the shutil code will recursively delete lots of files and directories, so explorer gets more time to get rid of the handle before your next `CreateFile` call happens. If you really wanted to know what happens, you would need to use windbg and do some kernel level debugging.